# Wildcard within if conditional of Bash fails to execute. Works when literal filename provided

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to execute a command depending on the file type within directory. But am unable to check the content within directory using wildcard. When provided a literal filename I am able to execute.

```
find ./* -type d -execdir bash -c 'DIR=$(basename {}); if [[ -e {}/*.png ]]; then echo "img2pdf {}/*.png -o $DIR.pdf"; fi ' \;
```

Comment: The file/directory/etc tests don't work with wildcards. See ["Bash check if file exists with double bracket test and wildcards"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615535/bash-check-if-file-exists-with-double-bracket-test-and-wildcards).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going over directories, and then looking for png-s inside, `find` can find png-s straight away:

```
find . -name '*.png'
```

Then you can process it as you do, or using [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
find . -name '*.png' | xargs -I '{}' img2pdf '{}' -o '{}.pdf'
```

The command above will process convert each png to a separate pdf.

If you want to pass all png-s at once, and call img2pdf once:

```
find . -name '*.png' | xargs img2pdf -o out.pdf
```

Comment: Oh that's because I want to have a consolidated pdf output of all the ```.png``` files, named after the directory recursively. I am now using ```[ -n "$(find {} -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png*' | head -1)" ] && img2pdf {}/*.png```

Comment: Ok, this is even easier. I've updated the answer.