# Find a file with .zip extension and assign it to a variable for later use in BASH

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have done the below:

1. Publish artefacts in Azure DevOps
2. From the artefacts, wants to locate the .zip file with values and assign it to a variable to pass later in CURL post.

There are zip files with .zip extension inside '/home/vsts/work/1/a/Package'
unzip:  cannot find or open AOS-01-94-2023-10-10_0101.zip, AOS-01-94-2023-10-10_0101.zip.zip or AOS-01-94-2023-10-10_0101.zip.ZIP.
AOS-01-94-2023-10-10_0101.zip

I am able to echo that says, it can identify the .zip files exists and can print the filename. But its just  the filename not the filename with content.

My code:

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |

  ```
          currdir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Package"

          if [ -e "$currdir"/*.zip ]; then
          echo "There are zip files with .zip extension inside '$currdir'"
          fi

          zip_f=("$currdir"/*.zip)
          echo $zip_f
          if [ ${#zip_f[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
             echo "No Zip File"
          fi
          z=${zip_f[0]}
          zipfilename=$(basename "$z")
          unzip -l $zipfilename | awk '{print $1 "\t"  $4}' | tail -n+4 | head -n-2
  ```

Comment: Obligatory hint: use https://shellcheck.net and fix what it reports. If that doesn't solve it, can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: Is `$( )` something that'll be substituted by azure? If it is, `$(basename "$z")` is invalid; if not, `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is probably wrong. Also, `[ -e  ]` can only test single files, not wildcard patterns (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615535/bash-check-if-file-exists-with-double-bracket-test-and-wildcards)) and `echo $zip_f` will only print the first element of an array (or [it might mangle it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)).

Comment: Tested your bash scripts in my pipeline, `zip_f` can only returns the name of my first zip file, which is consistent with what Gordon said. What's the value of your `zip_f`? Besides, add a `ls` command in your bash scripts and check whether the zip files are in your working directory.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. It only returns the name of the file not the contents. I would need the file along with its content.

Comment: @Subrajit Gupta, hi, have you tried the scripts below? Would you please let me know if it  works for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following scripts works fine in my pipeline. My .zip files are in the directory `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s`.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      currdir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s"
      for file in "$currdir"/*.zip; do 
        if [ -e "$file" ]; then 
          echo "There are zip files with .zip extension inside '$currdir'";
          break;
        else 
          echo No Zip File;
          break;
        fi; 
      done
      
      zipFiles=$(ls $currdir/*.zip)
      for zipF in ${zipFiles[@]}; do
        echo $zipF
        unzip -l $zipF | awk '{print $1 "\t"  $4}' | tail -n+4 | head -n-2
      done
```

Comment: The quotes are incorrect. `[ -e "$currdir/*.zip" ]` is only true if there is a file named literally `*.zip` in `$currdir`. But if you remove the quotes and have more than one file which matches the wildcard, you bump into a different problem. The proper solution is basically `for file in "$currdir"/*.zip; do if [ -e "$file" ]; then echo Found at least one file; break; fi; done`

Comment: Also, you failed to populate `zip_f`, and [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Hi @tripleee, thanks for your suggestion. I've modified the scripts based on your suggestion.

Comment: The second loop is kind of useless; you might as well roll it into the first (and then get rid of the still useless `ls` and the slightly weird use of an array where really you don't need one).